# Twilio voice integration working in debug mode but not in signed App

Tags: android, twilio, voip

**Error Log:**

System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.twilio.voice.impl.session.Account" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/packaege.name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/packaege.name-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/packaege.name-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

E/jni_mate: #
    # Fatal error in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jni-mate/workspace/configuration/Release/label/master/jni-mate/src/main/jni/classreferenceholder.cc, line 92
    # Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
    # error during FindClass: com/twilio/voice/impl/session/Account

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the misspelling of "package" in the path `/data/app/packaege.name-1`?

Comment: No I just have changed the original package name to package.name while posting the question